# Compositing Transparent Polygons with OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, alphablending, compositing

I have a 2D object that needs to be rendered to the screen as semi-transparent using OpenGL ES 2.0. However, the object is is composed of several overlapping polygons. When I use the blend function

```
 glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

the result is that the sections of the object where the polygons overlap is distinctly less transparent (which makes sense) For example, if I was rendering an object made of two slightly overlapping circles with alpha = .5, the region of the object where the circles overlap would only be 25% transparent while the non overlapping regions would be 50% transparent. However, my goal is to render the object with uniform color and transparency.

I am aware I can render the object as opaque into an intermediate texture, and then render the texture with the correct transparency to the screen. However, this particular draw call happens frequently with different objects (so I can't cache the result) and the intermediate step would be a significant performance hit. Can this be done without the intermediate step using OpenGL ES 2.0?

Comment: can you sort the object front to back? if so then enable depth testing so fragments behind a previously drawn object is not evaluated

Comment: @ratchetfreak The program currently does not use a depth buffer, but that would be a good idea if it did.

Comment: Or use a stencil buffer so only the first drawn fragment is kept

Comment: @ratchetfreak That would also work, but has the same issue of the depth buffer in that it is currently not being used. If there are no solutions that involve just the renderbuffer I will likely use one of these, thanks.